# Unload option is not there in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

Actually i am a VB6 developer, switching to VB 2010 (VB.NET), in visual basic we use to do Form1.unloadme
However, its not working in VB2010...

```
Form1.UnloadMe()
```

Even option is not available in intellisence.

Is there any book which i can refer to understand VB 2010 faster...

Comment: What does UnloadMe do? Is Form1 the Form class itself or an instance of the form?

Comment: There is no `UnloadMe` in VB6. I think you must mean either `Unload Me`, which is syntactic sugar for `Me.Unload`, or `Form1.Unload`. In `Form1.Unload` the `Form1` must be an instance of the form class. Of course it could be the implicit global instance created by VB6 with the same name as the class.

Comment: There are [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595198/best-book-to-learn-vb-net-for-intermediate-programmer) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965333/best-vb-net-book-for-vb-programmer) about books for VB

Comment: And [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887204/advanced-level-vb-net-book-recommendation-with-good-lambda-expressions-and-linq) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343380/is-there-any-book-like-c-in-depth-for-vb-net-devs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
Me.Close()
```

where "**Me**" will work as your current form i.e. Form1 and "**Close**" will work as UnloadMe option....

You can go for ***Evangelos Petroutsos*** Book, naming "**Mastring Microsoft Visual Basic 2010**" and published by Wiley-Sybex.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that just using myForm.Close() must be leaving instances of the same form in memory each time I called it. The memory usage showed a small form repeatedly opened with myForm.Show() was adding 1mb to the programs memory usage.
The code that I am using now not only works, but unloads the form from memory.

```
Dim myForm_Instance as New myForm
myForm_Instance .Show()
myForm_Instance  = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this <(o(00)o)>, improvise this code:

```
    Me.Hide()
    Dim FormNew As New Form1
    FormNew.Show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).